# Can I delete rows using user defined functions in oracle?

Tags: plsql, oracle9i, user-defined-functions

I created a user defined function to delete some data. It doesn't work with delete but works with select. I am Oracle 9i.

The function is something like this:

```
create or replace function UFN_PURGEDATA(INPUTID IN VarChar2) return number is
  Result number;
begin

  Result := 0;


   DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.ID=INPID;

  COMMIT; 

   Result := 1;
 EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN    

  return(Result);
end UFN_PURGEDATA;
```

Then I use `select UFN_PURGEDATA('test') from dual` to run it but got result `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is "no".

If you remove your error "handling" you will find that the delete is failing with an exception like:

> ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML
>   operation inside a query

i.e. you cannot perform an insert, update or delete from within a function called in a SELECT statement.

To execute this function in an IDE or SQL Plus, wrap it in some more PL/SQL like this:

```
declare
  l_result number;
begin
  l_result := my_function(123);
end;
```

However, you will need to add a RETURN statement to your function first otherwise it will fail.

(NB I said "handling" above in quotes because it is really "mishandling" - it completely disguises the actual problem in a very unhelpful way.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Then how can I execute this function? My ultimate goal is to call this function in a java program.

Comment: -1 The definite "NO" in this answer is incorrect. It is possible using autonomous transaction (see jonearles answer). There are issues with that approach but it is a possibility nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform DML inside a function used in a SELECT if you add PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION.  For example:

```
create or replace function UFN_PURGEDATA(INPUTID IN VarChar2) return number is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
  DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE MyTable.ID=INPUTID;
  COMMIT; 
  return 1;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN    
  return 0;
end UFN_PURGEDATA;
/
```

But you definitely want to avoid this approach if possible.  In general, there's no way to know how many times a function will be executed if it's used in a SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can delete rows using user-defined functions in Oracle, but not from within a SELECT statement.

There are a couple of problems with your code:
- you don't return a value if your function does not raise an exception
- you must not use a function performing DML in a SELECT statement; if you remove your exception block, you get an ORA-14551

Comment: Thank you for your help, too. Please advise me how to reach my goal. I want to call this function from a java program but also want to test it in PL/SQL Developer.

Comment: You should be able to call it from Java just like from PL/SQL with an (anonymous) PL/SQL block, using a bind variable for your return value - see Tony Andrews' Answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a procedure (instead of function) with OUT parameter returning the number?  Without doing the autonomous transaction trick, Oracle doesn't want you running functions (used in selects) with "side-effects" (understandable why we don't want a select to result in DML changes).